# 32 Bit JRE 1.8_0_60 Failed to launch web start application but same works with 64 Bit JRE 1.8

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

We have a JNLP based webstart application, it is launching and working fine with JRE 1.6,1.7 32 bit & 64 bit version (OS: Windows 7 Enterprise 64 Bit and Application Server: Websphere 8.5.5). With regard to JRE 1.8, application is launching fine with 64 Bit JRE but failed to launch with 32 Bit JRE. 
With 32 Bit 1.8 JRE, we are getting an exception that one of the groovy class is not found although that specific class is present inside Groovy 2.3.9 jar.  I also confirmed via Java Cacher Viewer that Groovy-all.jar is successfully getting downloaded to user cache folder (c:\Users{userid}\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java) when we launch initial JNLP

*Here is complete trace of the exception that we are getting*

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
    at com.sbc.etm.expressions.groovy.RestrictedMetaClass.get(RestrictedMetaClass.java:40)
    at com.sbc.etm.expressions.groovy.AbstractGroovyObject.<init>(AbstractGroovyObject.java:24)
    at com.sbc.etm.expressions.groovy.GroovyExpressionObject.<init>(GroovyExpressionObject.java:62)
    at ar8512_ETM_GroovyExpression_11.<init>(ar8512_ETM_GroovyExpression_11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sbc.etm.expressions.groovy.GroovyExpression.evaluateObject(GroovyExpression.java:205)
    at com.sbc.etm.expressions.groovy.GroovyExpression.basicGetDataTypeAndValue(GroovyExpression.java:199)
    at com.sbc.etm.expressions.Expression.getDataTypeAndValue(Expression.java:228)
    at com.sbc.etm.expressions.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:610)
    at com.sbc.etm.message.StringTemplate.evaluate(StringTemplate.java:280)
    at com.sbc.etm.message.StringTemplate.bind(StringTemplate.java:229)
    at com.sbc.etm.navigator.Node.getLabel(Node.java:195)
    at com.sbc.etm.navigator.Folder.toString(Folder.java:804)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sbc.etm.ui.framework.NodeBrowserRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(NodeBrowserRenderer.java:61)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.getDisplaySize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxUI.getMinimumSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at com.sbc.etm.ui.framework.lnf.metal.EtmMetalComboBoxUI.getPreferredSize(EtmMetalComboBoxUI.java:96)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.BorderLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at com.sbc.etm.ui.framework.NodePathBrowser.updatePreferredSize(NodePathBrowser.java:111)
    at com.sbc.etm.ui.framework.NodePathBrowser.<init>(NodePathBrowser.java:67)
    at com.sbc.etm.ui.framework.BusinessView.<init>(BusinessView.java:358)
    at com.sbc.etm.ui.framework.BusinessViewSpec.createBusinessView(BusinessViewSpec.java:186)
    at com.sbc.etm.ui.framework.ETMClient.openBusinessView(ETMClient.java:524)
    at com.sbc.etm.ui.framework.HomeBusinessView.open(HomeBusinessView.java:99)
    at com.sbc.etm.ui.framework.ETMClient.openHomeBusinessView(ETMClient.java:546)
    at com.sbc.etm.ui.framework.ETMClient.openETM(ETMClient.java:563)
    at com.sbc.etm.ui.framework.ETMClient.access$300(ETMClient.java:46)
    at com.sbc.etm.ui.framework.ETMClient$OpenETMRunnable.run(ETMClient.java:166)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What DLLs does the JAR file require?  It's likely it only provides 64-bit DLLs and not 32-bit ones.  Because the class is looking for a native implementation per this line:  `at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)`

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: which JDK was it compiled with?

Comment: Hi Andrew H - But it works with 1.6 and 1.7 32 Bit and 64 Bit JRE

Comment: Hi MPK - It is compiled with 1.8 32 Bit Java

Comment: Right now, I have identified only 2 workaround but both workaround has to be done manually in client machine which we dont want. Workaround 1:Workaround 1
In Deployment.properties located in “c:\Users\{userid}\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment” include this one line
                                deployment.trace.level=all

Now try to login to application, it successfully launches
Work.  Workaround2:Manually copy groovy-all jar to JRE lib\ext folder to client desktop and login to the application. Application launches fine